# Add 50% discount for every second product (Prestashop)

Tags: prestashop, price

I'm trying to figure out if it is possible in Prestashop create specific price rule which allows 50% discount for every second product in a row. I.e. 1st goes for $100, 2nd - $50, 3rd - $100, 4th - $50 and so on.
I was only able to achieve 50% for every product if there is more than 1 product.

Thanks in advance

Comment: What do you mean by “in a row”? In a row where - in my shopping cart, and therefor eventually the order I create?

Comment: I mean I have a product A costing $100, I want every even (2nd, 4th and so on) product A to get a 50% discount in the shopping cart.

Comment: It's not possible. I would create a pack of 2 products with $150. Then, even add in product accessories, so it could be visible when the customer was viewing the other product.

Answer (score 2):

By default is not possible, but you can achieve that with this module: https://addons.prestashop.com/en/promotions-gifts/9129-promotions-and-discounts-3x2-reductions-offers.html